# How do I select Properly Using "between" in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I am having a problem selecting between two dates. I tried to select data from  a SQL Server database, but the result is not that I wanted. Can someone help me?

I have 4 records from database where all formatted as GeneralDate

```
order_date
---------------------------
2018-07-17 07:10:40.000 AM
2018-07-17 07:10:40.000 AM
2018-07-16 07:59:23.000 AM
2018-07-16 07:59:23.000 AM
```

Here's the code

```
SELECT order_date 
FROM ORDER_RECORDS 
WHERE order_date >= '2018-07-16 08:59:23.000 AM' 
  AND order_date < '2018-07-16 08:59:23.000 AM'
```

Sample date is from a `DateTimePicker1.Value`.

The query shown returns zero results, since only the date is true and the time is false. As you can see the of the record of the database is starts at 07:59:23.000 AM, and the query which fetch data is starting 08:59:23.000 AM

Another example query

```
SELECT order_date 
FROM ORDER_RECORDS 
WHERE order_date >= '2018-07-16 03:59:23.000 AM' 
  AND order_date < '2018-07-16 08:59:23.000 AM'
```

Which returns two rows as result, since the query is staring from 03:59:23.000 AM

Here's the result

```
2018-07-16 07:59:23.000 AM
2018-07-16 07:59:23.000 AM
```

What I want is to fetch data between two dates and ignoring the time.

Comment: What application language are you using here?

Comment: visual basic 2017

Comment: Please give an example query against your sample data and then show what the expected output is.  There are several interpretations of your question.

Comment: Why are you [not using a parameterized command string](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/51470422/1)? Let the server decide whether the input needs to be escaped or quoted; provide actual `DateTime` parameter values, not strings that look like dates.

Comment: What data type is your `order_date` column?  Is it a type intended for date/time data or is it a type actually intended for text?

Comment: i use datetime data types for my column order_date

Comment: Safest and easiest is `col >= '20180716' AND col < '20180717'`

Comment: https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need convert datetime to date

<strike>SELECT order_date FROM ORDER_RECORDS WHERE order_date >= CAST('2018-07-16 08:59:23.000 AM' AS DATE) AND order_date < CAST('2018-07-16 08:59:23.000 AM' AS DATE)</strike>

Update:

```
SELECT order_date 
FROM ORDER_RECORDS 
WHERE CAST(order_date AS DATE) BETWEEN CAST('2018-07-16 08:59:23.000 AM' AS DATE) 
                                   AND CAST('2018-07-16 08:59:23.000 AM' AS DATE)
```

Update - datetime compare

```
DECLARE
    @StartDT DATETIME = CAST('2018-07-16 08:59:23.000 AM' AS DATE),
    @EndDT   DATETIME = DATEADD(DAY, 1, CAST('2018-07-16 08:59:23.000 AM' AS DATE))

SELECT order_date 
FROM ORDER_RECORDS 
WHERE order_date >= @StartDT AND order_date < @EndDT
```

Comment: it gives also zero result after using cast.

Comment: if order_date type also datetime, you need convert too

Comment: i tried to SELECT CAST(order_date AS DATE) as datecast FROM ORDER_RECORDS WHERE order_date >= CAST('2018-07-16 08:59:23.000 AM' AS DATE) AND order_date < CAST('2018-07-16 08:59:23.000 AM' AS DATE) but gives also zero result

Comment: try between <--

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34047/cast-to-date-is-sargable-but-is-it-a-good-idea